# How to generate Ember models based on it's Rails presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have a tons of models in Rails. I don't want to create the same for Ember by hands. What do you suggest?

Comment: Ember already has generators. Going to be hard to get more automated than that.

Comment: even if you only have around 10 models, when you create the ember side, you're not going to implement it all in one coding session.  just do the models you need and you'll be able to go through all of them.

Comment: I have thousands of models from legacy system. Anyway, I have to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

EmberCLI allows you to define [custom blueprints](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#defining-a-custom-blueprint) for generating entities. You could develop your own custom blueprint that generates Ember models from your Rails models.